# Time enabled Button with pug.js

Tags: javascript, pug

Hey i am fairly new to pug and cant figure out a way to make a button time enabled, so users take time to read a text before klicking continue.
I am using an express app and pug in combination with bootstrap.css for the templates.

pug File:

```
html
    head
        link(rel='stylesheet' href=`${baseRoute}/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`)
    body
        .container
            form(method='GET' action=`${baseRoute}/nextSite`)                
                div
                    p.mb-4= 'someText'
                button.btn.btn-primary.float-right.mt-4(type='submit', id= 'btn') Next
```

Javascript (express)

```
router.get('/start', (req, res) => {
  res.render('instruction', {
    baseRoute: 'the/base/route',
  });
});
```

Unfortunately i couldnt find any sources for handling this.

My idea was to modifiy the button in the pug file via javascript, but i cant manage to reference the button element

```
button.btn.btn-primary.float-right.mt-4(type='submit', disabled=true, id= 'btn') Next 
-console.log(btn); // undefined
-console.log(document.getElementById(btn); // document is undefined
```

Is this the right approach or am i missing something ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Disable the button, then use javascript to enable the button after the desired duration

Comment: and how do i enable it ?

Comment: By setting `button.disabled = false`

Comment: where ? something like ```-button.disabled = false;``` doesnt work, button is undefined in this case. i need to refer to the button element that i created prior.

Comment: Like I said, in your js file, set button to `disabled = false` after your desired duration

Comment: In my JS file, ```button``` as well as ```document``` are undefined so how should i access it. can you modify the JS code i provided pls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it.
pug-File:

```
                button.btn.btn-primary.float-right.mt-4(id='btn', type='submit', disabled=true ) Next
                script.
                    var button = document.getElementById('btn');
                    setTimeout(() => {button.disabled = false;}, 3000);
```